# Find The Remainder When $100^{100}$ Is Divided By 7

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the remainder when $100^{100}$ is divided by $7$.

I tried finding a pattern with the residues but it took a lot of time and I haven't found anything. Any answers? 
 Thanks!

Comment: Try taking a look at [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) and the related questions on the right.

Comment: [2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=100%5E100+mod+7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
100  &=2 \pmod 7 \\ 
 2^1 &=2 \pmod 7  \\
2^2  &=4 \pmod 7  \\ 
2^3  &=1 \pmod 7 
\end{align}

> $$ 2^{100} = 2^{ 3*33+1 }={ 2 }^{ 99 }\cdot 2 = 2 \pmod 7$$

Comment: Great answer, Battani!  Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 1):

Note that 100 has remainder 2 when divided by 7. So the problem is equivalent to determining the remainder of $2^{100}$. Hint: $2^3=8$, which has remainder 1. So $2^{100}=(2^3)^{33}\cdot2$...

Answer (score 1):

Using base $7$, $100_{10}=202$, and

$${202}^{202}\equiv{2}^{202}\equiv{2}^4\equiv2.$$

---

Indeed, as the base is the modulus, you can replace a number by its last digit

$$\boxed{abc}=7^2a+7b+c\equiv c$$

and by the little theorem of Fermat, you can replace a power by the sum of its digits

$$n^{\boxed{abc}}=(n^a)^{7^2}(n^b)^7n^c\equiv n^{a+b+c}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $200\equiv 2\pmod{6}$ and $3$ is a generator of $\mathbb{F}_7^*$ (or, simply, by FLT) we have
$$ 100^{100} \equiv 10^{200}\equiv 3^{200}\equiv 3^{2}\equiv 9\equiv \color{red}{2}\pmod{7}.$$

Answer (score 0):

We have $100=7\cdot 14+2=6\cdot 16+4$ Hence $$100^{100}\equiv 2^{100}\pmod7$$ Furthermore by Fermat's little theorem, $2^6\equiv 1\pmod7$ then
$$2^{100}\equiv(1)^{16}\cdot2^4\equiv2\pmod7$$

Answer (score 0):

A simple-minded solution is to just start dividing $7$ into $100^{100}$, or $1$ followed by $200$ zeroes.

The remainders for each successive zero in the continuing long division are $3, 2, 6, 4, 5, 1$;  this sequence then repeats, since the remainder of $1$ restarts the original division.

The $33$rd cycle of these 6 remainders ends at the $198$th zero. The next two zeroes leaves the remainder at $2$.

Answer (score 0):

$${100}^{100}=10^{200}=(7 + 3)^{200}$$
Using Binomial expansion
$$(7 + 3)^{200}=7k +3^{200} \space \text{where k is fixed integer}$$

Comment: This is a nice approach, but shouldn't it be $7k+3^{200}$?  This leaves finding $3^{200}$ mod 7, which other answers have worked out, e.g. using FLT.

Comment: @user128390 thanks , fixed it